# Visual Studio Android Emulator Is Not Running the Application

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android, emulation

When I deploy/run the Xamarin.Android app in Visual Studio (either pressing ctrl+F5 or play-button in toolbar), the Visual Studio launches its emulator for android (Note: It is "Visual Studio Emulator For Android", not SDK or any other emulator) without any difficulty and within a reasonable amount of time which works fine. But the problem is that it does not automatically run that app. Neither does it show any icon to run it.

Answer (score 0):

I have not had much success with the emulator built in to VS.

However, you need to switch your output to "verbose" and monitor the output window while it is attempting to deploy. This will give you a wealth of information during the deploy. Likely, your deploy is failing, this will help you figure ouy why.

As a side note, the free Genymotion is a much faster Android emulator that I have had great success with.